# Unity 2022.3.0: какая версия .NET?

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net

Пишу на C# библиотеку, которую в дальнейшем планирую использовать в составе игры, которую буду разрабатывать на Unity. Пока библиотеку разрабатываю и тестирую в составе консольного приложения C#. Я понял, что набор доступных функций .NET и фич языка сильно различается в зависимости от версии .NET. Не хотелось бы после подключения библиотеки к игре обнаружить, что она вызывает неподдерживаемые функции.
В [официальной документации Unity про поддерживаемые версии .NET](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) написано что-то совершенно непонятное и это совершенно не стыкуется со списком версий .NET в настройках проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую версию .NET использовать в проекте, в котором я разрабатываю библиотеку предназначенную для подключения к проекту Unity?

Предполагается использовать последнюю на текущий момент версию Unity: 2023.3.0.

Comment: Так поставьте соответствующий `NET SDK`, у вас видимо 4.x никакой не стоит, вот и не выбирается в `IDE`. Ну либо сама `IDE` настолько модерновая, что уже не поддерживает 4.x

Comment: @CrazyElf всё стоит, просто проект создан .NET а не .NET Framework. Но это не проблема, я написал ответ

Comment: @aepot Да я что-то про Standard то ли не знал, то ли забыл. Напридумывали тут. Я думал Framwork и Core только в тренде )

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2022 added .NET Standard 2.1
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык 2. по приведённой вами ссылке не наблюдается упоминание «standard 2.1»